# Custom Commands in Enumerate's Options

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

In trying to assume best practices and clean up code, I'd like to condense commonly used options for `enumerate` environments into a command with some arguments. However, [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) doesn't seem to like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\setlabel}[1]{label=#1, ref=Item #1}

\begin{document}

%   \begin{enumerate}[\setlabel{A}]
%       \item Something \label{item:a}
%   \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=A, ref=Item A]
        \item Something \label{item:a}
    \end{enumerate}

    \noindent Reference to \ref{item:a}.

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

The commented code would throw an error (`Package enumitem Error: label=A, ref=Item A undefined.`).

I'm aware of `SetEnumitemKey`, but [it doesn't seem to accept arguments](https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem/issues/9).

Ideally, the answer would also work with `\NewDocumentCommand` from [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) for more advanced meddling with optional arguments. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the same kind of list repeatedly, wouldn't it be cleaner to just define a new list type with the formatting you want?

Comment: @AlanMunn Unfortunately, that approach is less versatile and cumbersome for my purposes; I may want one list with roman `label`s and `ref`s, the other with arabic, the other with custom ones, etc. Defining a new list for each combination of options seems inefficient, and defining one new list with what all the lists have in common and then add options is, well, what `\begin{enumerate}[label=A, ref=Item A]` already is; I'm just looking to make this approach more concise, elegant, and maintainable.

Comment: @Mico If my understanding of these macros is correct, yes, they are, for this particular purpose, inefficient, cumbersome, and less versatile. See also my comment to your answer, I hope it clarifies the question.

Comment: @Mico I wasn't trying to be confrontational, I'm sorry you got that impression. I was just trying to clarify my question, and the inefficiency I perceive in one approach for this particular purpose is part of that, as it is the main motivation for my question in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `enumitem` uses a hand-made key-value system based on `xkeyval`. One could think to add a key and to define its associated effect to set the relevant keys, but the processing is strange and this doesn't work.

The code below is based on internals of the package, so it may become obsolete if the package changes.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\enitkv@key{}{setlabel}{%
  \expandafter\def\@itemlabel{#1}%
  \g@addto@macro\enit@delayedkeys{,ref=Item #1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[setlabel=A]
\item Something \label{item:a}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent Reference to \ref{item:a}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm sorry to hear about the difficulties of the implementation, but this is indeed precisely what I was looking for. A couple of questions: why do you say "this doesn't work"? It compiles without errors or warnings for me. Also, why does e.g. `\enitkv@key{}{setlabel}{\g@addto@macro\enit@delayedkeys{ref=Item #1}}` work, but with `label=#1` instead it doesn't? I suppose this might be what you meant by strange processing, so I understand if there's no clear answer to these. And here I thought `\setlabel` could just be made to become "`enumitem`-readable" text... :(

Comment: @steve It doesn't work if I define the macro `\setlabel` to do `\enit@setkeys{label=#1,ref=Item #1}`, which should be the way, weren't for the complicated processing of the keys.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misread that part. Thank you for the clarification!